# _path is generating the wrong path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't know why, but it is generating the path with a . instead of /

if I use 
link_to 'Destroy', @serie

it generates /series.1

so I had to use this:
link_to 'Destroy', series_path + "/" + @serie.id.to_s

In order to get /series/1

but this is a problem to submit, I would have to override it everywhere
Any ideas of what I've done wrong?

my routes file:

`Newepisode::Application.routes.draw do

resource :users

resource :series

resources :series

resource :episodes

resources :episodes

resource :user_serie

match "login" => "users#login"

match "logout" => 'users#logout'

match "signin" => "users#signin"

post "users/do_login"

match "series/load_other_series" => "user_serie#load_other_series"

get "admin" => "admin#index"

match 'user/:alias' => 'series#load_user_series'

match 'feed/:alias' => 'user_serie#feed'

root :to => 'series#main'

end`

Comment: You have something wrong in your routes.rb file, show us some code from that file

Comment: updated the question with the routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
resource :series    
resources :series
```

It should be

```
resource :serie
```

or

```
resources :series
```

[Edit]

The same stuff with :episodes...

[Edit]

This is basic stuff... you're getting this link: /series.1 becouse with this line

```
resource :series
```

you are telling rails that there is only one row in series objects, so the id of the object is irrelevant. You should remove this line and leave only

```
resources :series
```

and don't forget to restart server after that

Comment: I've tried that, but it wont work with only one.
when I use resource, the error is on /series/:id
when I use resources, I get some error loading the partials

Comment: it should be resources, if you having errors in your partials then problem is now in partials, not in routes... paste error message your are getting and maybe before read it and try to figure out what is wrong ;)